# how can I modify exporting .xls to xssfworkbook

Tags: java, excel, jsp, apache-poi

I have used `HSSFWorkbook` for importing .xls files but I need to import both .xls and .xlsx files using `XSSFWorkbook`. I need to convert both hssf sheets and xssf sheets into MySQL database..
Someone please help me with some code to import both .xls and .xlsx sheet into MySQL database. I already tried some code to import but in that code if we use `HSSFWorkbook` then .xls files are uploading but when I change to `XSSFWorkbook` but it showing error in `XSSFWorkbook` declaration..

```java
try {
    String company, currentPayor, dateofservice, balance, patient_name, led_age;

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/technosoftproj", "root", "mahi777777");
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement pstm = null;
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("C://Users//Nandana//Desktop//tasks.xlsx"));
    //POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input ); //creating a new poi reference to the given excel file
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row;
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) { //points to the starting of excel i.e excel first row
        row = (Row) sheet.getRow(i); //sheet number

        if (row.getCell(0) == null) {
            company = "0";
        } //suppose excel cell is empty then its set to 0 the variable
        else company = row.getCell(0).toString(); //else copies cell data to name variable

        if (row.getCell(1) == null) {
            currentPayor = "0";
        } else currentPayor = row.getCell(1).toString();

        if (row.getCell(2) == null) {
            dateofservice = "0";
        } else dateofservice = row.getCell(2).toString();

        if (row.getCell(2) == null) {
            balance = "0";
        } else balance = row.getCell(2).toString();

        if (row.getCell(2) == null) {
            patient_name = "0";
        } else patient_name = row.getCell(2).toString();

        if (row.getCell(2) == null) {
            led_age = "0";
        } else led_age = row.getCell(2).toString();

        String sq = "INSERT INTO tasks(company,currentPayor,dateofservice,balance,patient_name,led_age) VALUES('" + company + "','" + currentPayor + "','" + dateofservice + "','" + balance + "','" + patient_name + "','" + led_age + "')";

        pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sq); //here we are using prepared statement because we are calling this statement for each row
        pstm.execute();

        System.out.println("Import rows " + i);
    }
```

Comment: Use `WorkbookFactory` and the `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel` common classes, as per the [Apache POI docs](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#user_api)?

Comment: Can you send me some code snippet to work with...